# Kill a java launch4j-wrapped app launched with java Process api

Tags: java, launch4j

I use Windows.

I have a java application wrapped in an exe with launch4j. When I run it, I see two processes in my task manager: the exe wrapper, and the underlying java. When the program ends, both processes disappear.

When I run the exe with the command line, if I want to stop the process prematurely, I Ctrl-C, and both processes are terminated.

But in some cases, the program is run by another java application, with the process api. In this case, if the application must be stopped prematurely, I tried using `myProcess.destroy()`, but only the exe wrapper was stopped, the underlying java continued to run. I also tried `destroyForcibly()` with the same result.

Why the difference in behavior? How can I really emulate the behavior of Ctrl-C and kill both processes?

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. The problem is that when you use CTRL-C to kill the launch4j process, it will properly handle the SIG and kill the child. When you destroy a process it just ends it, and because the launch4j has no chance to end the process it spawned, it sticks around. You will need to get the child process that launch4j spawns and also end it manually. If Launch4j was updated to create a Job Object, this wouldn't be an issue.